# Download Manager is not working when setNotificationVisibility to hidden

Tags: android

It download file fine when setNotificationVisibility() is set to visible ,but it is not downloading when visibility is set to visible I am new to android please help me!.

Comment: `it is not downloading when visibility is set to visible` ? And what is `it`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this permission to the Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

**Note**
Most of the manifest permissions will be auto-completed by Android Studio, but this will not be auto-completed. Rest assured, it will work.